# File System Watcher in service is not processing files

Tags: c#, .net, service, filesystemwatcher

I need to start a FileSystem Watcher from a service. The filesystem watcher adds files to a list,a timer elapsed event runs some code every 1 second to process the input file from the list updated by the watcher

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    startwatching();
    System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    aTimer.Elapsed += ATimer_Elapsed;
    aTimer.Interval = 1000;
    aTimer.Enabled = true;
}

void startwatching()
{
    watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
    watcher.Path = watchpath;
    // labelControl10.Text = "Monitoring-> " + watcher.Path;
    watcher.Filter = "*.*";
    // watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.CreationTime;
    watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(copied);
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}

void copied(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    if (!robotprocesslist.Contains(e.FullPath))
    {
        try
        {
            robotprocesslist.Add(e.FullPath);
        }
        catch (OutOfMemoryException error)
        {
        }
    }
}

private void ATimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

But no files are processed. What i'm I doing wrong? Please advice.

Comment: Are you creating or changing the files while the process is running?

Comment: @pm_2 I'm copying the files to the watch directory to check.

Comment: Does `robotprocesslist` definitely have the file names in?  Have you put a breakpoint on to check?

Comment: Note a single line of writing to a log file. Instead a silent-exception-eating catch clause. That looks unsolvable to me.

Comment: @pm_2 I cannot debug the service directly .. i tried catching exception and writing to a text file.But no text file is produced.

Comment: What is `watchpath`? Are you changing files in that path? Is `copied` getting called? I think this is something only you can test. For us to help we would need a complete  example with test steps and expected behavior and actual behavior.

Comment: is the path a UNC? on another server?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your problem is here:

```
if (!robotprocesslist.Contains(e.FullPath))
```

I suspect that your list look like this:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
```

And it's checking against:

```
c:\file1.txt
```

And so never finding the file in the list.

As @Uwe Keim has pointed out - some logging might help proving this theory.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use a Queue instead of list and process your files in a dedicated thread. It's not clear what are you doing in the timer event, but it's quite possible that you try to process same files multiple times.

Your Created event is fired only once, when the file is created or file copy begins, and it will probably take a few seconds until it's done, so it's likely that your files are locked in your timer event. Files are locked as long as file is being copied, so you won't be able to do much processing until the file copy/creation is finished.

Take look at my answer here: [Using file.move to rename new files in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50321140/using-file-move-to-rename-new-files-in-c-sharp)
It's a console application test, which implements file processing in separate threads (one per file created).