# How to make FileSystemWatcher change event to execute only once when coping and pasting multiple files? C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, filesystemwatcher

the situation is this, I have a datagridview which load some data from an xml file, so, I use a function to load this information and into this function the first lines make a cleaning of the full datagridview, i'm using a FileSystemWatcher to handle events when a new file is inserted into a specific folder and refresh the table, it works fine when I only move or create one file, but when I move files to the folder, or copy & paste, the program throws an error message, I think it's because the event is firing for every copied or moved file, and it doesn't let to finish the get files method when it is cleaning again, i'm not sure if i was clear, i'm going to let you here the pieces of the code, the instance of the FileWatcher it's initialized in the constructor of the class that contains the GetFiles method

GetFiles method:

```
 public void GetFiles()
        {
            ds.Clear();
            this.dgArchivos.DataSource = null;
            this.dgArchivos.Rows.Clear();
            this.dgArchivos.Refresh();
            filesPath = Clases.Utilerias.RutaArchivos;
            this.lblFilePath.Text = filesPath;

        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(filesPath);
        var archivos = di.GetFiles("*.pdf");
        DataRow dr;

        //PASO 1 -- Cargamos el XML
        string rutaConfig = string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", filesPath, "config.xml");
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(rutaConfig);
        if (fi.Exists)
        {
            ds.ReadXml(rutaConfig);
        }

        //PASO 2 -- Agregamos los archivos que no existan en el xml
        foreach (var archivo in archivos)
        {
            if (!ExisteArchivoEnTabla(archivo.Name)) //antes de cargar los archivos a la tabla es necesario revisar si ya existe en ella
            {
                dr = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
                dr["FileName"] = archivo.Name;
                ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dr);
            }
        }

        this.dgArchivos.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        if (dgArchivos.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            int Total = (dgArchivos.Rows[0].Cells.Count - 2);
            dgArchivos.Columns[Total].DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = "Preview";
        }
        this.getFRunning = false;
    }
```

FileWatcherClass:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using ScanScraping.App;


namespace ScanScraping.Clases
{
    public class FileWatcher
    {
        public static frmProcessFile frm;
        public FileWatcher(frmProcessFile process)
        {
            frm = process;
            Run();
        }

        [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
        public static void Run()
        {
            // Create a new FileSystemWatcher and set its properties.
            FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            watcher.Path = Clases.Utilerias.RutaArchivos;
            /* Watch for changes in LastAccess and LastWrite times, and
               the renaming of files or directories. */
            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
               | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
            // Only watch text files.
            watcher.Filter = "*.pdf";

            // Add event handlers.
            watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
            watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnDeleted);

            // Begin watching.
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            // Wait for the user to quit the program.
        }

        // Define the event handlers.
        private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            // Specify what is done when a file is changed, created, or deleted.
            Console.WriteLine("File: " + e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);
            frm.formPadre.xmlCreateOrUpdate();
            frm.GetFiles();
        }

        public static void OnDeleted(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("File: " + e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);
            string[] file = e.FullPath.Split('\\');
            string fName = file[file.Length - 1];
            frm.updateXML(fName);
            frm.GetFiles();
        }

        private static void OnRenamed(object source, RenamedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Specify what is done when a file is renamed.
            Console.WriteLine("File: {0} renamed to {1}", e.OldFullPath, e.FullPath);
            frm.formPadre.xmlCreateOrUpdate();
            frm.GetFiles();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Simple: disable `watcher.EnableRaisingEvents` before you start processing files, and re-enable it afterwards. You may of course want to keep it as accessible object then, and not in that `static` function. Not sure why that is static anyway.

Comment: Perhaps this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50321140/using-file-move-to-rename-new-files-in-c-sharp/) can help you.